# Complex plane "deprived from" or "deprived of" closed disk?

Tags: phrase-choice, mathematics

Which of the following phrases are correct?

> Complex plane deprived **of** closed disk

or

> Complex plane deprived **from** closed disk

Comment: Neither one makes much sense.  What context is this in?

Comment: In mathematics. I am trying to define the domain of the plan where we have removed a disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't usually say "deprived from". It is correct to say "deprived of", but in most contexts your phrase would require at least one determiner. For example:

> We end up with a complex plane deprived of a closed disk.

By the way, "deprived" doesn't seem to me to be the right word here. Perhaps this would be better:

> We end up with a complex plane from which a closed disk has been removed.